# Authenticating users when they input the url into their browser

Tags: php

Try the following URL: https://cms1.gre.ac.uk/collaborativeprogrammes/student/index.asp

It brings up an authentication prompt with username and password which is separate from the accounts on their site; groups of users have the same username and password to gain entry, however once inside, you log in with you own username and password.

How could I implement this? i.e. the first authentication prompt only.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're hosting on windows then turn on windows authentication in IIS.
Your users would need their Active Directory credentials to log on.

OR

You can read this article on [HTTP Authentication in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: The second option would seem to be the most appropriate.  While the example provided by the OP is obviously running on a Windows server, there's no indication that s/he's trying to implement this in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an asp page, you can do this in php with .htaccess file

See this article:
http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/